# How can I change video (or image sequence) speed (slow or fast) in blender composition?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I want to use slow down effect in composition. I can't find any control. I found time node.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/input/time.html?highlight=time%20node#example

But I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with this area of blender, but for changing timings I think you want the video sequence editor not the compositor.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use Time remapping, a quick google search for that will help you.  Also when I get to a computer I will update this answer.

Comment: Time remapping will not work in my case. I want to change play back speed of one image sequence but I don't want to alter another sequence in composition. Time remapping will change speed of both image sequences. Thanks.

Comment: if you are using the video sequencer you can add an effect called speed control to your clip.